# How to use Microsoft Teams immersive reader to read adaptive card contents?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I'm creating a bot application for Microsoft Teams which respond to user with adaptive cards.
Now when the user is trying to use immersive reader to read the message aloud, the reader is not picking the card text.

Is there any way that will allow immersive reader to read card details?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any way to make this possible. As you may know, it is up to each channel/client to determine how to render/use/control adaptive cards. I tried using the [adaptive cards designer](https://www.adaptivecards.io/designer/), but wasn't able to find any settings/values that made any change to allow the immersive reader to work with any adaptive cards (even with simple text block).

I would recommend opening a ticket in the following repo:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams/issues